# How do NLP practioners assign the lamba for a feature in a maxent classifier?

Tags: nlp

I am watching the [coursera NLP video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LixC4OJcc9E) on maxent classfiers. In the video, Christopher Manning assigns lambdas to features based on how strongly they pick out some class. For instance, Manning says (~2:00) the feature = "proceeding word is in and word is capitalized" (ex. in Quebec) is likely to pick out a class location and so is given a positive weight of 1.8 -- but the feature = "word has an accent" gets a weight of -.4 because in American english it is more likely to pick out names rather than places. Manning then says (~4:21) that "perceptron algorithms" and "support vector machines" are sometimes used to pick out the weights of features -- before he goes on to show a maxent model that normalizes the feature weights. However, in his maxent example Manning still uses the lambdas that he just picked out around minute 2 of the video. Where do these lambas come from? Does the nlp practitioner just pick them out from domain knowledge (as Manning does) and then thinker with them until the algorithm comes out with the correct values? Is there a more systematic method? Am I misunderstanding something in what is happening in this video?

Answer (score 2):

That video was mostly about how to formulate the maxent model.  To find the actual values for the lambdas, you pose an optimization problem based on the training data to a learning system.  This subsequent video, [section 8.6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InuXtFCr3WA), shows how to solve that optimization problem to find the right weights.